# Could not find com.github.rey5137:material:1.3.0

Tags: java, android, dependencies, build.gradle, android-cardview

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ecommerce"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have been working on android studio nowadays but when I copied three dependencies the sync was not successful.Please help me out !!!!!
The dependencies which I copied from https://github.com/rey5137/material are given below

```
implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are also distribute this library via Jcenter.

You can add new repository to your `build.gradle`, which is main directory (root) of your project **(not in `app`!!!)**.

To the end of the file you should find `allprojects` with `repositories` inside. Here add new repository:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

So it should look like:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }        <---- add this line
    }
}
```

(section `allprojects` probably is on the bottom of the `build.gradl` file)